# Why does assigning a 'char' to a 'char' give a seg fault? C++

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I have a class that looks like this:

```
class myTreeNode
{
     public:   
        char Data;
        myTreeNode *childA = NULL;   //A's always go in child1
        myTreeNode *childT = NULL;   //T's always go in child2
        myTreeNode *childC = NULL;   //c's always go in child3
        myTreeNode *childG = NULL;   //G's always go in child4
};
```

However, when I go to assign `Data` a value, I receive a seg fault. I do this like:

```
root->childT->Data = p_data;
```

Where `p_data` is a `char = t` and `root` is a pointer created by `myTreeNode *root = new myTreeNode;`. Why when going to assign `Data` a value would I get a seg fault? Isn't it just the same as doing `char Data = 't'`?

Comment: Have you set `childT` to be non-null at that point?

Comment: No, I haven't, but now I will.

Comment: `root->childT->Data = p_data;` does more than just assign a char to a char, it dereferences two pointers. It's far more likely one of those dereferences is what segfaults. If you'd asked "why does dereferencing two pointers and assigning a char to a char segfault?" then you probably wouldn't have even needed to ask the question here.

Comment: NULL is obsolete in C++

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your children are not pointing to any memory location. You have only created a new instance for the root node. You are getting a segfault because you are dereferencing a null pointer.

For example:

```
class myTreeNode
{
public:
  char Data;
  myTreeNode *childA = NULL;   //A's always go in child1
  myTreeNode *childT = NULL;   //T's always go in child2
  myTreeNode *childC = NULL;   //c's always go in child3
  myTreeNode *childG = NULL;   //G's always go in child4
};

int main()
{
  // allocate memory
  myTreeNode *root = new myTreeNode;
  root->childT = new myTreeNode; // allocate child

  root->childT->Data = 'a';

  // delete allocated memory
  delete root->childT;
  delete root;
  return 0;
}
```